How to Map JDBC ResultSet to DTO: Enum-Based vs Generic Approach
I had an existing implementation that used an enum (EventRowMapper) to map SQL result set columns directly to fields in a DTO (EventDTO). This approach worked but required hardcoding each field mapping explicitly in the row mapper. Here’s an example of the original approach:
ID("id"),
NAME("name"),
START_DATE("start_date"),
END_DATE("end_date"),
TYPE("type"),
CREATED_AT("created_at");

private final String column;

public static RowMapper<EventDTO> getEventDTORowMapper() {
    return (rs, rowNum) -> EventDTO.builder()
        .id(rs.getInt(EventRowMapper.ID.column))
        .name(rs.getString(EventRowMapper.NAME.column))
        .startDate(rs.getDate(EventRowMapper.START_DATE.column))
        .endDate(rs.getDate(EventRowMapper.END_DATE.column))
        .type(rs.getString(EventRowMapper.TYPE.column))
        .createdAt(rs.getDate(EventRowMapper.CREATED_AT.column))
        .build();
}

However, this approach becomes cumbersome as the number of fields grows or when other DTOs need similar mappings. I wanted to create a more generic utility that could handle the mapping dynamically for different DTOs.
I refactored the code by introducing a more generic mapping utility (RowMapperUtils). This utility uses reflection to map the ResultSet values into a DTO based on the fields and types defined in the enum (EventRowMapper). I implemented an interface, ColumnMapper, which standardizes the mapping structure, making the code more maintainable and reusable across multiple DTOs.
New approach:
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public enum EventRowMapper implements ColumnMapper {
    ID("id", "id", DataType.INTEGER),
    NAME("name", "name", DataType.STRING),
    START_DATE("start_date", "startDate", DataType.DATE),
    END_DATE("end_date", "endDate", DataType.DATE),
    TYPE("type", "type", DataType.STRING),
    CREATED_AT("created_at", "createdAt", DataType.DATE);

    private final String column;
    private final String field;
    private final DataType type;

    public static RowMapper<EventDTO> getEventDTORowMapper() {
        return (rs, rowNum) -> RowMapperUtils.mapResultSetToDTO(rs, EventDTO.class, List.of(EventRowMapper.values()));
    }
}

The RowMapperUtils class provides a generic utility method mapResultSetToDTO() that dynamically sets the fields on the DTO based on the columns in the ResultSet. The ColumnMapper interface ensures consistency in how columns are mapped.
    public static <T> T mapResultSetToDTO(ResultSet rs, Class<T> dtoClass, List<ColumnMapper> columns) {
        try {
            T dto = dtoClass.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();

            for (ColumnMapper c : columns) {
                Field field = dtoClass.getDeclaredField(c.getField());
                field.setAccessible(true); // To prevent IllegalAccessException
                field.set(dto, getValueFromResultSet(rs, c));
            }

            return dto;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Failed to map ResultSet to DTO", e);
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to map ResultSet to DTO");
        }
    }

    private static Object getValueFromResultSet(ResultSet rs, ColumnMapper c) throws SQLException {
        switch (c.getType()) {
            case INTEGER: return rs.getInt(c.getColumn());
            case DATE: return rs.getDate(c.getColumn());
            case DOUBLE: return rs.getDouble(c.getColumn());
            case BOOLEAN: return rs.getBoolean(c.getColumn());
            default: return rs.getString(c.getColumn()); // String will be used here
        }
    }

Performance concerns and questions:
While this approach improves flexibility and maintainability, I’m concerned about the potential performance impact of using reflection to map the fields dynamically. In scenarios where performance is critical (e.g., high-volume queries), could this generic solution introduce overhead compared to a more explicit mapping approach?

Are there performance trade-offs I should consider when using reflection in this way?
Is this approach viable for production use in high-performance applications?
Are there any alternative methods or frameworks I should consider to handle dynamic mapping more efficiently? If so, which ones?


Have you measured the impact of using reflection?

Why don't you use an ORM like Hibernate?

That is why Sprng has the BeanPropertyRowMapper so you don't have to re-invent the wheel. If your mapping becomes complex you might want to consider something like JPA.

@JustanotherJavaprogrammer I haven't done a formal performance benchmark for this approach yet. My primary concern was maintaining flexibility for mapping between the database and DTOs. However, if reflection introduces noticeable overhead, alternatives like manually mapping fields or optimizing this utility might be worth considering.

@AndreySmelik I chose to stick with JDBC because, in my experience, JPA can introduce performance bottlenecks when working with large relational databases and complex queries. JDBC offers more control over how queries are executed, which is crucial for optimizing performance in this specific use case. JPA is great for simpler use cases, but for me, JDBC seems to be a better fit.

@M.Deinum Thanks for mentioning BeanPropertyRowMapper. I haven't tried it yet, but it's worth exploring, especially if it can simplify the mapping logic without adding much overhead. However, my current approach allows custom data transformations during the mapping process, which I think BeanPropertyRowMapper may not handle out of the box. Do you think there are ways to extend or customize BeanPropertyRowMapper for such scenarios?

To clarify, the approach I’ve shared is targeted toward handling larger and more complex queries where conditional statements are necessary within the query-building process. For simpler queries, I use Spring Data JDBC directly in my repository interfaces.
This method works perfectly for straightforward cases like the one above. However, with more complex requirements, including conditional logic or advanced joins, I find that JDBC combined with a custom mapping approach offers greater flexibility and performance compared to JPA.

For instance:
@Query("SELECT id, name, start_date, end_date FROM event WHERE type = :type")
List findEventByType(String type);

If you make it more complex you are re-inventing JPA. If it is slow you are probably doing it wrong (mapping to entities then convert to dtos comes to mind).

@M.Deinum Thank you for your input! I appreciate your point about avoiding unnecessary complexity, and I agree that re-inventing JPA isn't ideal in many scenarios. However, in my case, I chose JDBC because I’m working with a large relational database and need to handle highly complex queries that JPA struggles with.
Regarding performance, JPA often introduces overhead with entity management, caching, and lazy loading, which has caused issues for me in the past, particularly when optimizing for both read and write-heavy operations.

You don't need entities and then map those to DTOS (that is a bad practic e anywa) you can just write a query and map to dtos. The issues that are introduced are more often then not user error due to not understanding how things work. Just write the query you want with the custom DTO you need and JPA can do the mapping. As a rule of thumb use JPA entities only for persisting when reading you probably want optimized queries (either JPQL or SQL) mapped to dedicated result objects.

@M.Deinum Thank you all for your insights and suggestions! I appreciate the feedback regarding JPA vs JDBC. It’s clear that both approaches have their advantages depending on the use case. For now, I'll be continuing with JDBC due to the specific performance needs and complexity of my queries, but I'll definitely consider JPA in future cases where its abstraction and features might be more appropriate. Thanks again for the constructive discussion!

Sounds like you're re-implementing ibatis, which might not be a bad thing. They did allow using custom queries, while still enable mapping beans without doing it yourself. We used it for very code-heavy and large databases and it worked great, all queries went through procedures so there was no code generation. I took a quick look into your impl, and it's not bad, perhaps i'd cache the reflection Field code so you don't re-get field data on every resultset row.
